# Проблема с Python в Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Cinnamon) после попытки установить Anaconda3

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

Пытался установить Anaconda3. Вроде всё прошло успешно, только вот все попытки запустить что-то, связанное с этой штукой оказались безуспешными. Помучился немного и удалил всё это дело, следуя инструкции на сайте Anaconda. Затем при попытке запустить Python получаю в ответ:

> ImportError: No module named site

А если запускаю Python3, то получаю:

> Fatal Python error: Py_Initialize: Unable to get the locale encoding
>   ImportError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00007f848be2e700 (most recent call first): Aborted

Как мне теперь с этим бороться?
Ну и в догонку. Что могло пойти не так при установке Anaconda3?

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос пока закрыт. Не дождавшись ответов, я снова попытался установить Anaconda3. В этот раз всё прошло нормально. Теперь по умолчанию в системе Python 3.6 из комплекта Anaconda3. А если нужно запустить 2-й Python, то можно это сделать командой Python2. Меня это вполне устраивает.